# Django model form dependency modifying

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, forms

I have two mode form fields: `action` and `service`:

```
class InputsModelExtended(models.Model):
    service = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=SERVICE_CHOICES, blank=True)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=ACTION_CHOICES, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):      
        return self.input   
    class Meta:
       ordering = ["service"]
       unique_together = ('service', 'action')
```

I passed them to `form.py` and created model form:

```
class InputsModelExtendedForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = InputsModelExtended
    #fields = ['service', 'action', 'input']
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {'service': forms.fields.Select(attrs={'class': 'service_select_box'}), 'input': forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter an input', 'class': 'selectpicker'}), 'object': forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter an object', 'class': 'selectpicker'})}
```

Then i take ajax post request on changing first field:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var select_box = $('.service_select_box')
    select_box.on('change', function(e) {
        console.log('event ', select_box.val());
        data = { "csrfmiddlewaretoken": '{{ csrf_token }}', 'action': select_box.val()};
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajaxrequest",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {console.log('success', data);},
            error: function (data) {console.log('error', data);},
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

And now how should I adjust `action` field variants to option selected in `service`? I tried to post it to template through `ajax_text`:

```
def ajax_test(request):
choices = {'assistant app' : (('ask' : (('Choose action', 'Choose action',), ('ask.friends','ask.friends',)),
'wisdom' : (('Choose action', 'Choose action',), ('wisdom.wisdom', 'wisdom.wisdom'))}
if request.is_ajax() and request.POST['action']:
    action = request.POST['action']
    #message = "ur action is " + str(request.POST['action'])
    action_choices = choices[action.lower()]
else:
    message = "empty or not an ajax"
form = InputsModelExtendedForm(request.POST or None, action_choices=action_choices) #passing form to template
InputsAll = InputsModelExtended.objects.all() #passing all objects to template
return render(request, 'inputs_forms_css.html', {'form': form, 'InputsAll': InputsAll, 'id': id})
```

But `action` field doesn't seem to change without refreshing, although through ajax success response i get normal modified select:

```
Service: <select class="service_select_box" id="id_service" name="service">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="Apps">Ask</option>
Action: <select id="id_action" name="action">
<option value="Choose action">Choose action</option>
<option value="ask.friends">ask.friends</option>
```

Should second field select set be modified through jquery or it could be done another way? Thx in advance.

Comment: Django expects the choices for a field to be defined when the form is instantiated. If you change the choices on the client-side via ajax, but not the server side, your form won't have valid choices. My recommendation would be to set all of the available choices on the second select and just filter the visibility of the choices from the first select.

Comment: This also has the nice side-effect of not having to make any additional calls to the server and should be a faster user-experience overall.

Comment: @Brandon how is visibility can be filtered?

Comment: I would add a property to each option in the second select that corresponds to the related option in the first select. It could be a css class, data attribute, etc. Then you can add an on-change handler to the first select via JavaScript to hide any elements in the second select that don't match.

Comment: @Brandon i assigned .action_select_box class to second field. But by which jquery method this field can be filtered? .html() ?

Comment: I'll add an answer with some sample jQuery-based JavaScript to demonstrate the filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll need to iterate over the choices for the second field at the template level to add whatever property you want to filter on. In this example we'll filter the second select's options by the value of the first select.

```
var firstSelect = $('#id_first_select'),
    secondSelectOptions = $('#id_second_select option');

firstSelect.on('change', function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();

    secondSelectOptions.hide();
    secondSelectOptions.filter('[data-related-value="' + value + '"]').show();
});
```

Comment: how can be id_second_select options find with .find()? if previously i passed this tuple:('wisdom.fun', 'wisdom.fun'), can i show it by calling secondSelectOptions.find('wisdom.wisdom').show() ?

Comment: Sorry - my fault. I have changed it to use `.filter`

Comment: But even `secondSelectOptions.filter('wisdom.wisdom').show()` just hides this select box.

Comment: My example filters on a `data` attribute on the option elements. You'll need to adjust your code to do something similar to implement my example.

Comment: Thanks for your example and I'm ok with adjusting it, but i don't completely understand how and with which attribute filter django select form. I'm not talking about getting set of values, but for one defined test value.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not quite sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Creating a select form, we give it a select-set, right? My question is about filtering mechanism and retrieving(showing) only one defined value from second field in test purposes. Fro example second select has a set of options like service_choices = (
        ('Foo', 'Foo',),
        ('Bar', 'Bar',),
        ('Baz', 'Baz',),
    ) and i need to show "Foo" only.

Comment: You're wanting to filter the second set of results based on the value of the first select, correct?